# JSON data from AJAX script is not appearing in HTML table

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc-3

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $.ajax({
        url: '/blog/getposts',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (result) {

            var insert = '';

            $.each(result, function (index, item) {
                insert += '<tr><td>' + item.Name + '</td><td>' + item.Body + '</td><td>' + item.DateCreated + '</td></tr>';
            });
            $('#blogTable').append(insert);
        }


    });
});
```

It works when I don't try to insert any `<tr>` or `<td>` tags but nothing appears when I do include those tags. I also have Firebug but I don't know what to look for.

I want to display a table with headers for Name, Body, and DateCreated, then all the data for each entry listed below.

EDIT: my JSON results

```
[
{"PostId":4,"UserId":2,"Body":"testtat","DateCreated":"\/Date(1301692095627)\/","Name":"derper"},  
{"PostId":3,"UserId":2,"Body":"tesateat","DateCreated":"\/Date(1301692093497)\/","Name":"derper"},  
{"PostId":2,"UserId":2,"Body":"testest","DateCreated":"\/Date(1301692091527)\/","Name":"derper"},  
{"PostId":1,"UserId":2,"Body":"derprperp","DateCreated":"\/Date(1301692082100)\/","Name":"derper"}
]
```

EDIT: The InnerHTML paste from FireBug

```
<tbody><tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Body</th>
    <th>Date</th>
</tr>
```

EDIT: So this is my html:

```
<table id="blogTable">
<tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Body</th>
    <th>Date</th>
</tr>
```

If i change my insert to this:

> insert += `'<td>'` + item.Name + `'</td><td>'` + item.Body + `'</td><td>'` + item.DateCreated + `'</td>'`;

then the innerhtml output when i run the site is:

```
<tbody><tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Body</th>
    <th>Date</th>
</tr>
</tbody>
 <td>derper</td><td>testtat</td><td>/Date(1301692095627)/</td>
 <td>derper</td><td>tesateat</td><td>/Date(1301692093497)/</td>
 <td>derper</td><td>testest</td><td>/Date(1301692091527)/</td>
 <td>derper</td><td>derprperp</td><td>/Date(1301692082100)/</td>
```

so my problem is when I'm trying to add new rows, they don't show up, but when I just use cells (`<td>`), they show up. How can I add new `<tr>`'s into the `<tbody>`?

Comment: Please post the JSON that you are fetching. BTW, you don't really need to use `$.ajax()` here; [`$.getJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) is sufficient. ...Also, this sounds like a perfect use case for [`$.tmpl()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.tmpl).

Comment: Could you provide an example for either $.getJSON() or $.tmpl()? Or both? I tried using the $.tmpl() method, but it didnt show up either. I only want the Name, Body, and DateCreated to show up in the table.

Comment: What exactly is wrong?  I just tested your code and it worked as written..

Comment: I'm not sure exactly...when I insert the data like `<p>`+ item.Name `</p>` and so on, it works and shows up. But when I try to insert the data with `<tr><td>` tags, it doesn't work. maybe because I have extra fields being sent from the JSON request? (postid and userid).

Comment: So if you `console.log(item.Name)` it spits out the correct information? When you inspect the DOM using Firebug does it show the HTML tables or is the table blank?

Comment: if i do console.log(item.Name), it says "ReferenceError: item is not defined". and when I inspect the DOM, the table is blank

Comment: Something's not adding up.  If it works with `<p>` it will work with table rows too -- based strictly on what's shown.  Link to your full, unedited code on pastebin.com.   If possible, link to the target page(s) as well.

Comment: would using ASP.NET MVC3 have something to do with it? I also didn't put <tbody> in my table html code, since apparently it is automatically inserted when I run the code. maybe that could be the source of `<p>` tags working but not `<tr><td>`?

Answer (score 0):

The code you've posted, so far, works.   See: [jsfiddle.net/SQVz6/](http://jsfiddle.net/SQVz6/) .

Using Firebug, inspect table: `blogTable`. (Right-clicking on the table will usually show Firebug's "Inspect" tool in the context menu.)

[image: Inspecting the table source using Firebug.]

~~~~~~~
Does the table structure look right?
Right-click on `<table id="blogTable">` in the inspector and then click `Copy innerHTML`
Paste the results into your question, above.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `.append()` to `.appendTo()`?

Answer (score 0):

after many hours of trying to figure out a solution, i changed the insert statement to this:

```
 $('#blogTable tr:last').after(insert);
```

and it works now. innerHTML output came out as follows:

```
<tbody>
<tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Body</th>
    <th>Date</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>derper</td>
    <td>testtat</td>
    <td>/Date(1301692095627)/</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>derper</td>
    <td>tesateat</td>
    <td>/Date(1301692093497)/</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>derper</td>
    <td>testest</td>
    <td>/Date(1301692091527)/</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>derper</td>
    <td>derprperp</td>
    <td>/Date(1301692082100)/</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Well, it's good that you've got it working, but it still makes no sense. Both insert statements work, irregardless of the presence of explicit `<tbody>` elements -- at least on (Chrome, FF, and IE8).   Something was missing here.